# Chrome extension content script not working on google.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a basic chrome extension that is supposed to insert a h1 tag to the html of specified site (`google.com/*`), when I run the code on other sites it works and the h1 tag is present but when I change the extension manifest for the scripts to run on google.com it just doesn't work.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Extension Name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["./main.js"],
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**main.js**

```
let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.id = "headerEl";

h1.textContent = "Test";

document.body.appendChild(h1);
```

When I tried running the same script on other sites it worked.

Comment: In an extension I wrote I wrote the matches as `"matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],` which works. Try this maybe

Comment: @TKret96 that didn't solve the issue

Comment: Your extension works as you can see in devtools inspector. Your content is not visible because the site is showing itself on top of it via CSS. You can use CSS yourself to raise the element via z-index.

Comment: @wOxxOm that is not right you see the id I'm giving the h1 tag? I was using getElementById in console to verify it is there. The problem was the browser I was using opera for some reason didn't work as soon as I switched to chrome everything started working

Comment: Opera has a setting in chrome://extensions for each extension to enable it on a search page.